# PyMySql alternative for pandas.io.sql in Python 3.4(windows 64)

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, mysql-python

i been using pandas.io.sql
 with PyMySql for awhile, the only problem i have is its REALLY slow for large datasets, the stored proc i call run in seconds, but it takes >15 mins to return.

i have tried with MySQL conenctor/Python 2.0.3 and alpha release 2.1.1 (mysql.connector.connection), it just hangs there with no reaction. MySQLDB doesnt work with python 3.4 so i can't try, anyone else tried any other ways?

```
cnx = pymysql.connect(user='user',
      password='pw',
      host= '127.0.0.1',
      port=3306,
      db='mydb',
      autocommit=True)
df=psql.read_sql_query('call sproc', con=cnx)
```

Comment: Does it help if you use `chunksize`? (see http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_sql_query.html)

Comment: Not really due to nature of my app, its real-time with sizes that varies wildly from time to time. beside my app, does chunksize really improve speed? i seen some other guy's queries and it seems it didnt really improve speed